# How to align the svg with the viewBox for variable size tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, viewbox

I have a D3JS tree and managed to download it as a SVG file. using the below code I managed to get the svg size and set the viewBox size accordingly (with 2% padding).

```
$('#download-SVG').click(function() {
    var svgElement = document.querySelector('svg');
    let {width, height} = svgElement.getBBox();
    var canvasWidth = Math.ceil(width + (width*.02));
    var canvasHeight = Math.ceil(height + (height*.02));

    var svgContent = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svgContent.setAttribute('viewBox','0 0 '+canvasWidth+' '+canvasHeight);
    svgContent.setAttribute("width", "100%");
    svgContent.setAttribute("height", "100%");
    svgContent.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");
    svgContent.appendChild(svg.node()); 
    .
    .
    }
```

example of my svg file with small number of nodes is

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 308 295" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><g transform="translate(501,21)scale(0.7)"><path class="link" stroke="#ccc" fill="none" stroke-width="2px" d="M50,195C50,285 -115,285 -115,375"/>....</svg>
```

example of my svg file with many number of nodes is

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1368 3122" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><g transform="translate(449,36)scale(0.7)"><path class="link" stroke="#ccc" fill="none" stroke-width="2px" d="M352.5,555C352.5,645 22.5,645 22.5,735"/>...</svg>
```

My issue now, is that depending on the svg size which is dependent on the number of nodes expanded or collapsed, the svg and viewBox are always out of alignment.  Expanding the tree to many nodes, shifts the svg to the left and collapsing to a small number of nodes, shifts the svg to the right.

I tried to set the x and y coordinates of the viewBox, but it never aligns exactly and make it align in all cases.

If I open the svg in InkScape and manually move the svg to the ViewBox, it fits nicely.

Comment: Maybe the problem you have is that you are translating the wrapping group. Please try removing the transformation. Also the bounding box have a `x` and a `y` properties. Use those (instead of 0) as the first and the second value for the viewBox

Comment: zeroing the wrapping group translation as well as viewBox coordinates places the root node of the svg at 0,0 coordinate.  The problem is that the tree is not symmetrical and placing the root node in the center of the viewbox places the other nodes outside it.  Each of these node  (rect) are scaled to 70 by 30.  It would be great if there is a way to align the viewBox 0, 0 with the svg 0,0

Comment: After removing the transformation from the wrapping group do a getBBox() on this group. You will get the position and the size of the bounding box. `let bb = theGroup.getBBox()`. Now you can use the result to build the new value of the viewBox="bb.x bb.y bb.width bb.height"

Comment: @enxaneta I managed to follow your advice and get the group x,y and W,H, however, it leaves empty spaces around the group.  If I use the SVG values, it is the exact size but shifted and no longer within the viewbox.  the dimentions of the two are as follows:  svg x-12.249987602233887 svg y 9.600000381469727 svg width 1340.5 svg  height 3060.39990234375  and the group values  bb.x -1017.5 bb.y -22 bb.width 1915 bb.height 4372

Comment: @enxaneta I used these variations svgContent.setAttribute('viewBox',' '+bb.x+' '+bb.y+'  '+bb.width+' '+bb.height);  which works but with spaces around the group and svgContent.setAttribute('viewBox',' '+bb.x+' '+bb.y+'  '+canvasWidth+' '+canvasHeight); which fits but shifted